# C++ output in browser

Tags: c++, browser, output, cout

I have a C++ program that runs nicely and it gives my output in the terminal when it runs, this is handy if the algorithm takes time.

How do I **'cout' the output in a terminal styled div in the browser** (doesn't allow user to type into it as an actual terminal)

Alternatively is there a different C++ command to direct output elsewhere other than the terminal window in which it is currently running?

Kind of new to C++ so maybe this is a obvious fix but thanks anyway

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking but you may want to look up `GCI` **C**ommon **G**ateway **I**nterface. (GOOGLE gave me this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm)

Comment: You mean like a [CGI "script"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)?

Comment: by the looks of it from what  @Galik said, that is what I am looking for...are these particularly tricky to get to grips with?

Comment: @Eoin In my experience the hardest part is configuring the web-server. :-)

Comment: ok brilliant thank you and in your experience, where would be the best place to learn best practices for this configuration?

Comment: @Eoin I have not used GCI in years tbh. But I posted a tutorial link I found on google in my first comment.

Comment: Outstanding!! that's the job, thanks very much to both of ye lads, cheers!